# Spring Boot - metrics for MeterBinder never registered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-micrometer

Situation: You have a metric registered in Spring Boot via a MeterBinder. Maybe it one of the auto-configured metrics like `jvm.gc.pause1` or it could be a custom metric of your own. But one day, you start your application and it is missing. It isn’t reported, it doesn’t show in Actuator, it’s just gone.

Root Cause: Probably your code or a library you are using is injecting the MeterRegistry. There are lots of legitimate reasons to do this, so don’t blame yourself. But injecting the MeterRegistry means that it will be created and initialised before all your beans are created, including possible MeterBinders.

It is also possible nothing is injecting MeterRegistry, but Spring has decided to create it before the MeterBinders for some other reason. Whatever the case, MeterBinders will stop working for you and there isn’t much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to create my own post-processor:

```java
@Component
class FixMeterBinders implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    ObjectProvider<MeterRegistry> meters;

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if(bean instanceof MeterBinder) {
            ((MeterBinder)bean).bindTo(meters.getObject());
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

There is a big downside to this approach: If Spring’s post-processor is working as intended, each MeterBinder will be run twice, so you need to make sure the work they do is idempotent.